# Tufte's margin notes in LyX instead of marginpar

Tags: lyx, tufte

Is there an "idiomatic"/non-ERT way in LyX 2.3 to add a margin note in a document formatted using `tufte-handout`?

The normal margin notes are not converted into `\marginnote`s as I expected but into normal `\marginpar`s (that do not have have the nice layout and typography of `\marginnote`).

How can I tell LyX to turn my margin notes into `\marginnote`s without having to resort to ERTs?

Comment: Try if `\let\marginpar=\marginnote` in LyX>Document>Settings>Preamble will do the job. A bit hackish, but latex is like that all around.

Comment: You can make your own inset that uses the command directly, by following the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109361/12212