# Custom Text Style in Lyx Doesn't Show Up In Compiled Documents

Tags: lyx

I'd like to define my own custom text style in order to highlight definitions. I came up on this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109353/shortcut-for-typewriter-font-style-in-lyx/109361), and I tried to follow its example to create a custom text style called 'definition', which is simply bolded cyan text. The 'definition' style shows up in the menu and it looks correct in Lyx, however when I compile my documents, the text is in the typewriter font (similar to the code text style) not mine. I've captured this behavior in a screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Lyx vs Compiled Code]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
 \newcommand{\definition}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
this is a \definition{definition}
\end{document}
```

---

Update: I think the crux of the problem is the line  `\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\texttt{#1}}`. It seems this is the only line of the local layout that actually makes it into LaTeX, and it doesn't seem to contain the information that \definition should color and bold the text. Unfortunately,  I don't understand the syntax or semantics of this line, (I got it from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109353/shortcut-for-typewriter-font-style-in-lyx/109361)), so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Replace  `\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` with `\newcommand{\definition}[1]{{\color{cyan}#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` does indeed only set text in typewriter font and contains no information on bolding or color. This is what the `\texbf` and `\textcolor` (from the [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package) commands do:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\definitiontt}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is a \definition{definition}

This is another \definitiontt{definition in typewriter font}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]